Selector functions in datatypes in the Z3 SMT solver - do they have to be unique?
In the Z3 SMT solver, consider a datatype of the following form, where the 'time' selector is shared between two alternatives in a datatype (the two selector functions extracting the time have the same name):
Command = Datatype('Command')
Command.declare('mk_move_cmd', ('time', IntSort()), ('distance', IntSort()))
Command.declare('mk_turn_cmd', ('time', IntSort()), ('turn_angle', IntSort()))
Command = Command.create()

This works for me when writing constraints and finding a model, but it does not work in this context:
if model.eval(Command.is_mk_move_cmd(command)):
    name = 'mk_move_cmd'
    time = model.eval(Command.time(command)).as_long()
    ...

suggesting that such selectors must be unique (have a different name for each alternative).
Can someone confirm that they have to be unique, and perhaps cast light on why it works in the context of model finding but not in the second context above?
Constraint solving works, but when I try to extract the time value from the model I get 0 for all applications.

I guess they have to be unique (since they are just functions), according to https://smt-lib.org/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf, page 61, where it says: "Similarly, constructors and selectors are function symbols, so none of them can be a previous declared/defined function symbol. This has the effect of also prohibiting, for instance, the use of the same constructor in different datatypes or the use of repeated instances of the same selector in the same datatype."
However, it seems to work partially which is interesting.
